# Improve animation smoothness (moving of controls)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have implemented the animation of moving of a grid control in the following manner:

```
<Grid 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding ElementName=rootLayout, Path=IsVisible}" 
            Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"                      
                    From="-500,0,0,0"
                    To="0,0,0,0" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Style>

  <Border 
      Grid.RowSpan="2" 
      Background="Black"
      CornerRadius="6" >          
    <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect />
    </Border.Effect>
  </Border>

  <TextBlock 
      Grid.Row="0" 
      Width="400" 
      Height="200" 
      Margin="20,20,20,10" 
      Text="{Binding Path=MessageText}" />

  <Button 
      Grid.Row="1" 
      Margin="20,5,20,15" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
      Width="75" 
      Content="OK" 
      Command="{Binding Path=CloseDialogCommand}" />

</Grid>
```

The animation works fine, but it's ugly. It is shaky / jittery / jerky and it really looks unprofessional. Is there a way to improve this? Am I using the right approach with animating the value change on the `Margin` property in order to move the grid? I've read about `RenderTransform`, but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Also, the animation looks unnatural. I know this can be improved but I don't know how. What are these properties and can they help me enhance my animation:

- `AccelerationRatio`
- `DecelerationRatio`
- `EasingFunction`
- `IsAdditive`
- `IsCumulative`
- `SpeedRatio`

Thanks for helping!

P.S. I am trying to put as much code as possible in XAML, so I'd prefer that approach, but really, if there's anything to improve this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use easing functions, a simple DoubleAnimation and RenderTransform, e.g.

```
<Button Content="Test">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X"
                                     From="-500" To="0">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

This should be quite smooth, check out [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751.aspx) on easing functions to get an idea of how they affect the animation.

Also note that the duration has a strong effect on what an animation looks like, depending on what easing function you use setting high duration values is needed because they slow down significantly at the end.

Comment: Thank you, this has improved my animation. One note though, the performance of the animation in terms of shaking is the same, but I think it's due to quite short duration time - so, using render transform or thickness animation appeared to produce the same result as far as that is concerned. The link you have provided is very useful, thank you especially for that.

Comment: I found a page where it is explained how to impact a frame rate of the WPF application. The page article actually explains how to reduce the frame rate, but in my case I need the opposite. So, I increased the frame rate from the default 60 to 120 and now the application animations work like a charm. Here's the link to the article http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/wpf-reducing-cpu-consumption-for-animations/

Comment: The question is how many users will benefit from that, if the display does not support a high enough refresh rate it will look *worse* than with 60fps. (I'd estimate that at the vast majority of portable computers have a refresh rate of 60Hz for which the default is likely to be suited best, even for desktop PC i suspect you normally don't find motiors with rates above 96Hz all that often)

Comment: Entirely agreed! However, I am coding on a laptop, which has refresh rate of 60Hz and once I changed the frame rate value from 60 to 120, it actually does make a difference. No idea how, but it does help with animation smoothness. I triple checked the results with both frame rate values and I honestly see an improvement. Weird...