# How to transform an image in a grid both in x-direction and y-direction in c# and wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a game similar to atomica in C# and WPF. I have a 4*4 grid in which three random images are generated. I must move image from present position to some other position in grid. I have starting position and end position of grid cell number and I have the path through which image or object must move through grid cells.

Here I am not able to animate to move the image first in x-direction for two cells then y-direction for one-cell and then one-cell in x-direction and so-on, so that I am able see the path in which the image is moving.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think this: [Improve animation smoothness (moving of controls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671515/wpf-improve-animation-smoothness-moving-of-controls) is a good solution also with suggetions how to make the animation smooth.