# WPF Animation Not Smooth

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, animation

I am trying to produce a simple closing doors animation in WPF, but cannot get it to be smooth - it is too jerky.

#### See for yourself

Here is a video screencast showing the issue:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/97qdnhk2w6jbi5s/wpf-animation-not-smooth.mp4?dl=0

#### Dead-ends

- I have tried to replace the brushes to plain solid colors, but still choppy
- Slowing down the duration of the animation - still not smooth
- Setting DesiredFrameRate to [a lower value](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/wpf-reducing-cpu-consumption-for-animations/) or [to a higher value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671515/improve-animation-smoothness-moving-of-controls) does not help
- [Easing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671515/improve-animation-smoothness-moving-of-controls) do not seem to help either
- The issue may arise on HD displays only (I'm testing on 1920x1200) ?

#### XAML to Try

```
<Window x:Class="Smth.ShellView" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            WindowState="Maximized"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            ResizeMode="NoResize"                      
            Topmost="True"
            WindowStyle="None"
            MinWidth="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}"
            MinHeight="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}}"                
            x:ClassModifier="internal"  >
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0" Color="White"/>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger
  RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:3">                    
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="leftDoorMove" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:6" >
                </DoubleAnimation>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rightDoorMove" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:6" >
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="leftDoor" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="leftDoorMove" X="-950" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="rightDoor" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="rightDoorMove"  X="950"  />                
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>          
</Window>
```

Comment: Cel, your animation works very smoothly on my machine.  I wonder if your computer is not letting the animation be handled by the hardware?

Comment: Your video shows an image in the background, I'm not seeing that in the xaml. You've also got a transparent background on your window. Have you tried running without these? If the image requires scaling that will impact the redraw, also although opacity is 0, it still adds to the draw process having the background in there. Otherwise, loom to other processes that may be impacting performance on your machine.

Comment: @kidshaw The image in the background is a Windows desktop wallpaper :) And when I disabled the transparent background and had it just white, no performance improvement unfortunately :(

Comment: Right that makes sense now. Honestly, it sounds as though it might be a local machine performance issue. I can't see anything here that should be causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try would be setting the scaling to low quality. 
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imageObject,BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);

Comment: what should i use as imageObject with the XAML i provided and where should i set this scaling?

Comment: also, i tried this sample app on a different PC with a non-hd display and while it was slightly smoother if you look at it you can see the "doors" still kind of stop/flicker briefly a few times - the animation is not smooth all the way, and I'm not being a perfectionist here..